# Why does the `find` command use a single dash for multicharacter options?

Tags: command-line, find

Is there any reason why the `find` command goes against the convention 
of using double dashes for multiple character options?

I mean, for example, why

```
find -name "my_file.*"
```

rather than

```
find --name "my_filename.*"
```

Comment: Just the way the source code is written. Two dashes is more typical of bash scripts (long options) and may or may not be used in c or other languages. You can examine the code yourself if you wish - https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/

Comment: Those are not options, but tests, and we already have a convention of multi-character test names with single hyphens - the shell's `[`/`test` command's tests.

Comment: There is no "convention", just the results of programmers making decisions, over time. Some decisions are earlier than others, some decisions are better than others.

Comment: @muru I think your comment is a good answer...

Comment: @muru That is indeed the answer--that they aren't actually options. This is a pretty common question/misconception about `find`; it would be nice to have an answer explaining it. I recommend posting an answer about it. (Even if you decided to just post that comment as an answer without any further expansion, I would upvote it.)

Comment: I've obtained an elaboration of [Muru's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946526/why-does-the-find-command-use-a-single-dash-for-multicharacter-options/1348764#comment1504998_946526) in another Stack Exchange [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78678/500714).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@muru said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946526/why-does-the-find-command-use-a-single-dash-for-multicharacter-options#comment1504998_946526):

> Those are not options, but tests, and we already have a convention of multi-character test names with single hyphens - the shell's `[` / `test` command's tests.

Comment: that logic doesn't apply to `-maxdepth`, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply history. Don't over-interpret those things; back when those old Unix commands were invented, there were no conventions, at least not anyway as strong as today. Everybody was doing his own thing. It took a long time until all that was settled, and by that time it was so established that there would have been an outcry, and a lot of carefully hand-crafted scripts would have broken, if there would have been a movement to unify those things.